# Put numbers into different piles

Tags: c++, vector, deque

I have a row of numbers and I want to put it into piles. The way that it's put is you look at the piles (they should be always ordered by size) and if you find a pile in which the number is smaller than the first number in that pile you put in front of the pile; if it's bigger than the last number in the pile you put it at the back of the pile. If none of the above is true you make a new pile. For example:

Input:

```
2 5 4 3 4 5 7 6 5 0 // 0 is used for end of input
```

Output:

```
3 4 5 7
2 5 6
4 5
```

The program compiles and works, but not the way it should (different results). The code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
  void sort_by_size( vector<deque<int>>& container )
   {
     for(int i=0;i<container.size();i++ )
      for(int j=i;j<container.size();j++)
        if(container.at(i).size()<container.at(j).size())
            swap(container.at(i),container.at(j));
   }
int main()
{
  int n;
  vector<int> all_dishes;
  while(n!=0)
   {
     cin>>n;
     if(n!=0)
     all_dishes.push_back(n);
   }
  vector<deque<int>> piles ;

  for(int i=0;i<all_dishes.size();i++)
  {
    sort_by_size(piles);
    bool smaller = false;
    bool greater = false;
    for(int j=0;j<piles.size();j++)
    {
        if(all_dishes.at(i)<*piles.at(j).begin())
        {
            piles.at(j).push_front(all_dishes.at(i));
            smaller = true;
            break;
        }

        if(all_dishes.at(i)>*piles.at(j).end())
        {
            piles.at(j).push_back(all_dishes.at(i));
            greater = true;
            break;
        }

    }

    if ( smaller==false && greater==false )
    {
        deque<int> temp;
        temp.push_back(all_dishes.at(i));
        piles.push_back(temp);
    }
    /*cout<<i<<":"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<piles.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<piles.at(i).size();j++)
          {
            cout<<piles.at(i).at(j)<<" ";
          }
    cout<<endl;
    }*/ //for looking what happens at each iteration
}

  for(int i =0;i<piles.size();i++)
   {
      for(int j=0;j<piles.at(i).size();j++)
       {
        cout<<piles.at(i).at(j)<<" ";
       }
    cout<<endl;
   }
  return 0;
}
```

Any ideas what is the problem with the algorithm and how to fix it?

Comment: Please **edit** your post and include the results you're getting. This way everyone doesn't have to run your program to find out what they are.

Comment: `sort_by_size` may use `std::sort` (with custom comparator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems.

First of all, your `n` variable is not initialized. That should trigger a compiler error.

Second, you try to dereference the element from the `end()` iterator. That's not possible, because that points to the one past the end of the sequence, so `end()` is not dereferentiable. You should use `back()`.

In other word, this

```
if(all_dishes.at(i)>*piles.at(j).end())
```

should become this:

```
if(all_dishes.at(i) > piles.at(j).back())
```

With these changes your program outputs the expected result.

Comment: I agree that dereferencing the `.end()` iterator is the problem; the second iteration of the data should have the 5 added after the existing 2, not in a new heap.  That alone should be enough to make the OP do elaborate printing to determine what on earth is going on.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem. I guess I should be more careful with `begin` and `end` and use `front` and `back` instead.